# How to end for loop on tkinter askopenfilename when cancel is pressed?

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

This function loops, to gets files from the user, until the last `spreadsheet_name` has been iterated over. The issue is that when the cancel button is pressed on the Tkinter `askopenfilename` modal window, it just continues to loop until the for loop is finished.

- Tried to add `if not self.file_name: break` to the beginning of the function but this throws an error because it does not exist yet.
- Tried to add `if not self.filename: break` to the end of the function but this does not work because `self.file_name` is a list.
- Tried to add `while self.file_name != '':` with same result.

```
    def get_files_from_user(self):
        for name in self.spreadsheet_name:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo(
                message='Please select {} Report'.format(name))
            self.file_name.append(
                filedialog.askopenfilename(
                    title="Select {} file".format(name),
                    filetypes=(('excel files', "*.xls"),
                               ("all files", "*.*"))))
            if not self.file_name:
                break
```

I would like the for loop to end if a variable in the list named `self.file_name` comes back empty/none.

Bonus help: What use is a return statement at the end of this function?

Comment: you have to get value from `askopenfilename` and check if it is `None` before you `append()` to list. Or check if last item on list is not None `if self.file_name[-1]` is not None:`

Comment: you don't have to use `return` if you don't need it. It will automatically use `return None` at the end but you don't have to get this value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get value from `askopenfilename` and check if it is not `None`, and then `break` loop or `append()` value to list.

```
def get_files_from_user(self):
    for name in self.spreadsheet_name:

        tk.messagebox.showinfo(
            message='Please select {} Report'.format(name))

        result = filedialog.askopenfilename(
                title="Select {} file".format(name),
                filetypes=(('excel files', "*.xls"),
                           ("all files", "*.*"))))

        #if not result: 
        if result is None: 
            break

        self.file_name.append(result)
```

Comment: Solid answer! I ended up adding an end of list check `[-1]` and it worked but I think I like the way this is written more. Thanks!